# How to use the i18n() function with i18next js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, internationalization, i18next

i have imported the i18next js plugin into my backbone application. The Plugin is configured and ready to work.

```js
// initialize i18next plugin
i18next.init(
  {
    lng: language,
    debug: true,
    resources: data,
  },
  function(err, t) {},
);
```

When i add the data-i18n attribute to my html element im' not able to translate his text:

```
<p id="test" data-i18n="myKey"> label </p>
```

and the js:

```
$('p#test').i18n()
```

the **i18n()** function is **undefined**

Comment: Do you use is it with https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next?

Comment: Maybe files are loaded in wrong order?